# Interrogation on DB with PHP textarea

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database

Hi guys i want to do some query on my DB (i use MySql) gived by an input TextArea and want to show the resurts, i tried like this :

```
    <textarea id="area"rows="4" cols="50" name="query" form="form1">
    </textarea>
    <input type="submit"onclick="take()"value="do">
```

this is the js function

```
    function take() {
     var query = document.getElementById("area").value ;
```

then i use a php function to show the table result

```
function stamp($query){

$result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['conn'], $query);
// stamp $result ecc...}
```

can somebody help me to fixate this and have some advice for the stamp function ? ty

Comment: Firstly, carefully filter the variable `$query` (your function parameter) since I'm thinking (Based on your question) that user's will directly place SQL commands into the textarea.  For example, what if a user put in `DROP TABLE users`

Comment: Being that you want to perform queries without going to another page, I'd suggest putting the function `stamp` and other related PHP code on its own PHP script page and have your javascript function `take` send the text of your command to said php script via AJAX.  Then you can return the results to a DIV of your choosing if you like.